# How to paste 2D Arrays onto each other

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to simply stack two 2D arrays onto each other like this, if I have two 2D arrays like this:

```
a = [[0, 0],
   [0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1],
   [1, 1]]
```

I want this output:

```
ab = [['01', '01'],
     ['01', '01']]
```

It is important that the final array elements (e.g. 01) are one string and not seperate elements(like ['0','1']).
I've been trying with zip and dstack but cannot get it right.

Edit: I didn't mention this in the OP but the output matrix should also have the same dimensions NxN dimensions as the 2 input matrices.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]` and `b = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]`?

Comment: @JacksonFreeman please correct again

Comment: Op has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a double comprehension list

Edit: Added an int cast to make sure the values don't get interpreted as floats

```
a = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]

result = [[str(int(i)) + str(int(j))] for c,d in zip(a,b) for i,j in zip(c,d)]
result = [[result[0][0], result[1][0]], [result[2][0], result[3][0]]]
print result

[['01', '01'], ['01', '01']]
```

Comment: When I run this code i get a slightly different output as you. Some characters are added to the string: [['0.01.0'], ['0.01.0'], ['0.01.0'], ['0.01.0']] . The '0...0' shouldn't be there. Any idea what causes this? Maybe some setting somewhere?

Comment: are you defining `a = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]` and `b = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]` as you posted in your question? It looks like in your case the numbers are getting interpreted as floats instead of integers. I'lll update my answer to convert them to int

Comment: For trying to figure things out I was simply using a = numpy.zeros((2,2)). Using different arrays helped. Thank you!

Comment: but you've built (1,N**2) line-shaped array instead of (N,N) matrix.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually quite an interesting question if array dimensions are quite large.

You can try `dstack`+`apply_along_axis` approach. Here, `dstack` would sandwich two your arrays atop each other, and `apply_along_axis(.. , 2, ..)` would apply a conversion function to each 1x1x2 canapé of that sandwich.

The trick is to provide conversion function, here I propose "convert to int, convert to string and join strings" as a simple nested lambda.

```
import numpy as np

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: ''.join(map(lambda y:str(int(y)),x)), 2, np.dstack((np.array(a),np.array(b))))
```

```
>>> a = np.zeros((10,10))
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> b = np.ones((10,10))
>>> b
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])

>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: ''.join(map(lambda y:str(int(y)),x)), 2, np.dstack((a,b)))
array([['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
       ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01']],
      dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: This indeed works great for bigger arrays. However it does not seem to be any faster than just using a simple double nested loop where I just iterate through all elements of both arrays and paste them in a new array.(which is the method im currently using)

Comment: to make further speedup you might consider trading off speed/memory and employ aggressive function result caching.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following if you want the result as strings, otherwise remove the str method

```
c = [[str(x[0]) + str(y[0]), str(x[1]) + str(y[1])] for x, y in list(zip(a, b))]
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working. However, i get some weird extra characters in my strings : [['0.01.0', '0.01.0'], ['0.01.0', '0.01.0']]. Any idea what the reason could be ?

Comment: I guess it's because your numbers are floats. Try to do `str(int(x[0]))...`

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Any idea on how to expand this function for matrices of different sizes ? say two input matrices of 20x20. Right now it only outputs a Nx2 matrix. I forgot to mention in the OP that I need the output matrix to always be the same dimension as the input matrices. And the dimension of these input matrices can vary, albeit always equal dimensions to each other

Comment: Doesn't the last commentary do the trick ? Don't think it will get any better than that

Comment: Yes, but quite slow. I think that method works a lot slower then this one. And speed was quite an important parameter here

Answer (score 0):

If both 2D arrays always have same size `m*n`, you can try using this basic nested-looping:

```
a = [[0, 0],
   [0, 0]]
b = [[1, 1],
   [1, 1]]
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        temp.append(str(a[i][j])+str(b[i][j]))
    c.append(temp)
```

Comment: This was indeed my first attempt. However, the code is used on quite larger arrays than the one in my OP so i was trying to find a faster way than this. Using this loop takes my code around 15 sec to paste all my arrays but does work correctly

Comment: It's quite tempting to use `numpy.vectorize` to replace that loop, because while it is essentially same loop under the hood, but it provide convenient result caching for duplicate values, which might speed up execution a lot.  Try to test it to be sure.